# How to connect all the points of a map using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I would like **to make a map showing points and connecting every one of them with the others**, like a *network*. I know that I have to use some sort of loop or combination, but I stack in this last step. Please, I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

```
setwd("C:/data")

# Plot a simple map of the Spanish-French border without any detail
xlim <- c(-3.36, 4.78)
ylim <- c(40.17, 44.63)
map1 <- map("world", col="#f2f2f2", fill=TRUE, bg="white", lwd=0.05, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)

# Plot nodes
locations <- read.csv("locations.csv", sep=";")
symbols(locations$longitude, locations$latitude, bg="#e2373f", fg="#ffffff", lwd=0.5, circles=rep(1, length(locations$longitude)), inches=0.05, add=TRUE)

# Plot links [here is where I need your HELP!], the following code do not achieve my goal...
for (i in 2: length(locations$longitude)-1) {
  lngs <- c(locations$longitude[i], locations$longitude[i+1])
  lats <- c(locations$latitude[i], locations$latitude[i+1])
  lines(lngs, lats, col="#e2373f", lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt (I haven't tested this code):

```
connectTheDots <- function(index) {
  remainingIndices <- (index + 1):nrow(locations)
  for (j in remainingIndices) {
    lngs <- c(locations[index, "longitude"], locations[j, "longitude"])
    lats <- c(locations[index, "latitude"], locations[j, "latitude"])
    lines(lngs, lats, col="#e2373f", lwd=2)
  }
}

for (i in 1:nrow(locations)) {
  connectTheDots(i)
}

# this is essentially a nested for loop,
# but I tried to make the syntax simpler by making a function first
```

Comment: I need your help again... how can I do it using great circles? I know I have to apply the gcIntermediate function but I get confused  reading the tutorials. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: This is a good topic for a new question. I haven't used the geosphere package before (nor gcIntermediate), so it'll be good to ask other people too. Leave another comment on here to let me know when you've asked a new question, and I'll give it a look

Comment: Thanks Reed. Tomorrow I will post a new question as you have proposed. I will leave here a link as well!

Comment: Hi Reed. I have just add a new question here: http://goo.gl/HF4JYv Hopefully someone will give me a hand. Ramiro.